# java script multiplication function

Tags: javascript

i'm doing a simple form that multiplies the inputs using the function "multiply" but it doesn't work. Could someone help me please. one more think, when do we put parameters for the function ?
my code is :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
    #resultDiv {
        font-size: 24pt;
        text-align: center;
        color: green;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
 <input type="text" id="firstnum">
 <input type="text" id="secondtnum">
<button onclick="calculate()"> press here </button>
<div id="resultDiv"></div>

<script>

function multiply () {
    return firstnum * secondnum;  
}

function displayInResultDiv(v){
        document.getElementById("resultDiv").innerHTML=v;
    }


function calculate (){


    var firstnum=document.getElementById("firstNum").value;
        var secondnum=document.getElementById("secondNum").value;
        var result=firstnum * secondnum;
        displayInResultDiv(result); 
    }


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `firstnum` is not the same as `firstNum` and `secondtnum` is not the same as `secondNum`. Voting to close as off-topic due to typos. Please use the browser console the next time, before asking a question.

Comment: Sorry, i'm just a beginner :) Didn't know how to view it from the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct the typo at `secondtnum` and `firstnum` as currently you are using `ids` which are not there in the HTML markup.

> [**`document.getElementById()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById), *returns a reference to the `element` by its `ID`; the `ID` is a string which can be used to identify the `element`; it can be established using the `id attribute` in `HTML`, or from script.*

```js
function multiply() {
  return firstnum * secondnum;
}

function displayInResultDiv(v) {
  document.getElementById("resultDiv").innerHTML = v;
}

function calculate() {
  var firstnum = document.getElementById("firstnum").value;
  var secondnum = document.getElementById("secondtnum").value;
  var result = firstnum * secondnum;
  displayInResultDiv(result);
}
```

```css
#resultDiv {
  font-size: 24pt;
  text-align: center;
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="firstnum">
<input type="text" id="secondtnum">
<button onclick="calculate()">press here</button>
<div id="resultDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Rayon

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the parameters for a function in the parentheses where you define the function. `multiply` should be

```
function multiply(firstnum, secondnum) {
  return firstnum * secondnum;
}
```

Even though the parameters have the same name as the variables in `calculate`, you need to declare them as function parameters. Functions cannot see variables from different fuctions. (This is called "scope", and lets you re-use variable names in different parts of your program.)

Comment: I still don't get it, when shall i put parameters cuz i thought that the're optional.

Comment: Every variable that you use inside a function either needs to be a parameter or a new variable that you've created inside the function. (With `var some_variable = ...`). You can create a function that doesn't have parameters, but only if you don't need to pass any variables into the function.

Comment: Thanks for your help Andrew. Now i get it :D